# sed regex not working for hidden characters

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I have a list that has for some reason got some non alphanumeric characters appended to the end.

I would have thought it would be a simple case of running :

```
sed 's/[^A-Za-z0-9]$//'
```

To replace these trailing characters.  Unfortunatley the above seems to be having zero effect.

For example, if I hex dump the file, I will see lines such as :

```
63 6f 6d be 0a
```

Obviously, the culprit here is the hex character

```
be
```

But running the following pipe

```
.... | sed 's/[^A-Za-z0-9]//' | hexdump -C
```

I still see "be" appearing !

Comment: You need the Kleene `*`. Use `sed 's/[^[:alnum:]]*$//'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the characters you don't want with `tr`; in your case

```
... | tr -d -c '[:print:][:cntrl:]'
```

`-d` deletes any character matching the specified characters, `-c` complements the character sets (so it keeps only what matches in this case), `[:print:]` matches all printable characters including space, and `[:cntrl:]` matches control characters (such as carriage return and newline, which you probably want to keep).